# Retrieving file installation path from registry for cmd application

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted the installed application path to be retrieved from the registry. This is the batch code for your reference:

```
@echo off
REM Batch Script for Prepar3D V4
REM Add the current Folder to the Addon Library (add-on.cfg)

set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%
call "D:\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4\Prepar3D.exe" "%args%"
```

I expect the "D:\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4\Prepar3D.exe" location to be retrieved from registry.

Comment: I don't know why you would expect that. Type `call /?`.

Comment: You're going to first need to know where in the registry the path is stored, and then you're going to need to change your code to read from that location. The first you can figure out using `regedit`. The second you can make an effort to do by searching this site for `[batch-file] read value from registry`. Once you've gotten that far and made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulty, you can come back and ask for help with the issue you've encountered.

Comment: @Noodles, that is where the cmd will refer to run and add the config file.

Comment: @KenWhite I have the regedit code `REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4" /v SetupPath` But I am not sure how to change `call "D:\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4\Prepar3D.exe" "%args%"` from my above codes so that it will change the current value as `D` drive to the actual path where the software were installed.

Comment: That information should be in your question. As it's currently written, it's a *plz givez me teh codez* post. Your efforts so far are relevant, and your actual question is not what you've asked above. You're asking how to use the results of `REG QUERY` in place of the `call` statement, and that's not what the question currently asks.

Comment: Type `for /?`. `For` can process command output.

Comment: I notice that you're using `Path=%cd%` in your arguments, how are you running this script? and how have you determined that the current directory is the location you require for `Path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example should `Set` the location for your specific program and from your stated registry key and value to the variable `%Dir%`:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4"
Set "Val=SetupPath"

For %%A In (Cmd Reg)Do Set "%%A=%SystemRoot%\System32\%%A.exe"
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 Set "Cmd=%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe"
Set "Dir="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    ""%Cmd%" /D /C ""%Reg%" Query "%Key%" /V "%Val%" 2^>Nul""')Do Set "Dir=%%~B"
If Not Defined Dir GoTo :EOF
If "%Dir:~-1%"=="\" Set "Dir=%Dir:~,-1%"
Rem Your commands go below here.
Echo "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe"&Pause
```

I have added an example command line at the bottom to hopefully show you the executable complete with its full setup pathline. You would obviously replace that with your required commands but please first take note of the other comments you have received first, *especially due to your incorrect use of `Call`*.

*Please also note that I have had to make some assumptions in my answer because I do not have a system I can replicate your environment in.*

Because `v4` of your program is for `x64` Operating Systems only, the code checks only in the `64-bit` registry. It is designed so that it will check the `64-bit` registry regardless of whether the script is being run from a `32` or `64` bit process.

**[Edit /]**
As a courtesy for providing confirmation that the code works as intended, I have decided to post an example of 'your commands':

```bat
Set "Pad=%~dp0"
Set "Arg=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add"
Set "Arg=%Arg%, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%Pad:~,-1%"
Start "" "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe" "%Arg%
```

*Simply replace `Echo "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe"&Pause` in my top code with the `4` lines above.*

Comment: Thanks for the codes. I have edited my question. Maybe you may refer that if my question before is not clear enough. Hope you can guide me.

Comment: Really sorry. I was reading the upper comments before reading your answer. There were people saying my questions was not clear. That is why I changed the question to make them clear. Please advise. I am a new by on stackoverflow. Never been asked much of questions before. So not aware of the procedure well.

Comment: I think you have seen the codes that I was attach before. Maybe you could have something like that? I am not a coding guy. I got 0 knowdlge about batch coding. So, it’s quite hard for me to understand it. But I tried with your codes. It seems not working. Maybe you can put the whole code in your answer with my rem codes included.

Comment: My code should work unless there's something you haven't told me, or have not checked properly before creating your question.

Comment: I have tried your code, but it doesn't work.

```If "%Dir:~-1%"=="\" Set "Dir=%Dir:~,-1%"
Rem Your commands go below here.
REM FlyTampa Batch Script for Prepar3D V4
REM Add the current Folder to the Addon Library (add-on.cfg)
set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%
Echo "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe"&Pause```

Please correct me if the code i placed after ```Rem Your commands go below here.```  is wrong.

Comment: @Manochvarma, your question asks to retrieve the location from you provided registry key and value, and that is what I have attempted in my answer. Please run my code, exactly as I have posted it, any additions or modifications are outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: Ok. Where should I place my batch code which is in the question above to make it work? Otherwise I can’t confirm your code work for my context.

Comment: @Manochvarma, before anyone is able to suggest a way forward on your subsequent commands, you must provide the resultant output from the exact script I have offered, _(without modification or additions)_.

Comment: I can confirm that you code able to retrieve the location of _Prepar3D_ from the registry. Thank you for it. :) Could you now please guide me to make it work with the code I have provided?

Comment: I have manage to find out the complete code to make it work. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Manochvarma, please see my [Edit /], for an example of the lines you'd use at the remarked location.

Comment: thank you for the edited code. Is that possible to make it with `if` and `else` statement too? Something like, if the path is not in the `addon.cfg` file, then the path is created. If it is already written on the `addon.cfg` file, then when we run the script, it will delete the path. Example: `if  addon == ""
   set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%
else
   set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Remove, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%
start "" "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe" "%args%"`